# Regex: How to replace truncate characters up to a given character?

Tags: regex, sed

I need to truncate with `sed` everything up to and including a certain character in a line (in this case it's `]`).

Typical lines:

```
*15:36:40,038 [Some text] More text ...*
*15:57:40,038 [123] More text ....*
```

Put another away, replace everything up until the `]` with nothing. What's the neatest way of achieving this?

In prodiving suggestions, I'd be very grateful for an explanation of the regex (or usage of the bash `cut` command), to further my knowlegde.

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

You must do it this way:

```
sed 's/[^]]*\]//'
```

**Example**

```
$ echo 15:36:40,038 [Some text] More text ... | sed 's/[^]]*\]//'
More text ...
```

**Explanation**

- `[^]]*` means any symbols except `]`
- `\]` means `]`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to cut everything till the last "]" (e.g. there are more [..] pairs) you could  try:

```
awk -F']' '{print $NF}' file
```

example:

```
kent$  echo "15:36:40,038 [Some text] More text ... "|awk -F']' '{print $NF}'
 More text ... 


kent$  echo "15:36:40,038 [Some text] xxx yyy [some other foo] More text ... "|awk -F']' '{print $NF}'
 More text ...
```

your example with cut :

```
kent$  echo "15:36:40,038 [Some text] More text ... "|cut -d] -f2                            
 More text ...
```